# Limits and continuity question

Tags: real-analysis, proof-writing

Let $f:D \to R $ be continuous at $c \in D $ and suppose that $f(c) > \alpha$. Prove that there exists an $\alpha > 0$ and a neighbourhood $U$ of $c \ni f(x)> \alpha$ for all $x\in U \cap D$

Anyone wants to help me get started on this proof?

Answer (score 0):

$f^{-1}((f(c)-{{f(c)-\alpha}\over 2},+\infty))$ is such a neighborhood $U$ since the inverse image of an open interval is open.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to notice is that if you show this for $\alpha=0$, then by considering the function $g(x)=f(x)-\alpha$ the result follows. Then setting $\epsilon =\frac{f(c)}{2}$ for the epsilon delta definition of continuity will give the result.

Comment: Can you explain why you set $\epsilon =\frac{f(c)}{2}$?  How did you come up with that number?

Comment: You want values so that $f(x)>0$, and you know that $f(c)>0$, so values less that $f(c)$ away from $f(c)$ will be greater than zero. The dividing by two is just a habit you get into with these problems.

Answer (score 0):

You could start with writing out the definitions. What does it mean for a function $f$ to be continuous at a certain point? (hint: something with $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s.) What is the formal definition of a neighborhood?

Then look at what those definitions mean, can you substitute extra information from the question?

Also: do you already have the intuition of why it is true? If not, you could try to make a drawing of the situation and see if it is true. Or, negate the conclusion and make a drawing of that situation. Then play a little bit until you have the intuition behind the statement, before you start writing the proof.